# Porting webkit layout engine

Tags: layout, webkit

I want to port webkit based browser to my stack. Can anyone tell about the organisation of the webkit browser engine? Currently what i know is that it has cores for rendering html & parsing javascript. I would like to know more, like how the javascript and renderer cores interact with each other?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.webkit.org/ is a website for the WebKit Open Source Project

Comment: Unfortunately, that site is not particularly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There don't seem to be official porting instructions. The next best thing is to use the simplest existing port as a reference and change things as needed. That may be WPE:

> WPE is the reference WebKit port for embedded and low-consumption computer devices. It has been designed from the ground-up with performance, small footprint, accelerated content rendering, and simplicity of deployment in mind, bringing the excellence of the WebKit engine to countless platforms and target devices.

https://webkit.org/wpe/

https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/WPE

The port to the Enlightenment desktop environment may also be one of the simplest:

https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/EFLWebKit